# Denied access resource in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I am playing with gitlab continuous integration possibilities, wanting to build and push a simple docker image.

Here is the .gitlab-ci.yml file :

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
- deploy

dockerhub:
  stage: deploy
    - docker build --pull -t registry.gitlab.com/yvnicolas/test-node -f Docker/Dockerfile .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/yvnicolas/test-node
```

The build itself is ok but fails to push with a access deny message. Here is the end of the trace of the job

```
Successfully built 8b99fc09ac4c
Successfully tagged registry.gitlab.com/yvnicolas/test-node:latest
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
Login Succeeded
$ docker push registry.gitlab.com/yvnicolas/test-node
The push refers to a repository [registry.gitlab.com/yvnicolas/test-node]
a936d383687d: Preparing
62ef757d064b: Preparing
5dda7fb6dd53: Preparing
72c708771a73: Preparing
099f37abad88: Preparing
d7bd42f1f660: Preparing
8b375be9de19: Preparing
0f8361255952: Preparing
71ce2dc7f761: Preparing
0d960f1d4fba: Preparing
8b375be9de19: Waiting
0f8361255952: Waiting
71ce2dc7f761: Waiting
d7bd42f1f660: Waiting
0d960f1d4fba: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I do not see what's wrong here...
Here is the [Project on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/yvnicolas/ci-node-docker-sandbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image name should be `registry.gitlab.com/yvnicolas/ci-node-docker-sandbox:latest` not `registry.gitlab.com/yvnicolas/test-node:latest`